# How to get StorageKey associated with an address?

Tags: polkadot-js, rpc, api, json-rpc

StorageKey keyword mentioned in the RPC substrate docs and polkadotJS RPC API docs
https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc#getkeyskey-storagekey-at-blockhash-vecstoragekey

How to get this StorageKey?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the apps UI to create keys, generally if these are single items this is a quick approach. In the apps UI via the storage page, you can see the encoded keys based on the input parameters (along with a breakdown on the right as to which component is due to which part)

[image: system.account query]

Additionally (and this is most probably not applicable for your case, however I'm including it here for future reference), you can also do it programatically via the JS API.

```js
console.log(
  // each api.query.<module>.<method> has .key exposed that
  // generates an encoded storage key
  api.query.system.account.key(
    // any parameters that you would need
    '1363HWTPzDrzAQ6ChFiMU6mP4b6jmQid2ae55JQcKtZnpLGv'
  )
);
```

The above would output the same details as found in the apps UI screenshot above, i.e `0x26aa...2f28`  which is the key for that specific account at this storage location.

Comment: thank you so much @Jaco. You have been a really supportive member of the community. I really appreciate your efforts :)

Answer (score 2):

Great question!

If you have a prefix of a storage key that you are looking for, you can specify in the first argument like so:

[image]

> Note that if you specify `0x` you will get all the keys!

If you want to know how the storage keys are created I recommend reading:

- https://www.shawntabrizi.com/blog/substrate/querying-substrate-storage-via-rpc/